# How do I remove people's intestines?

Tags: surgeon-simulator-2013

I'm trying to remove someone's intestines, but I can't figure out how. I can cut the small intestine on the left and the large on the right, but pulling on the large intestine doesn't do anything, and I can't grab the small intestine. I've tried cutting everywhere, but I don't see any new spots to cut and that makes him die fast.

[image]

Are there other requirements before I can take them out? If so, what are they?

Comment: I'm at work atm so i can't check and know for sure, but there are 2 spots on each intestine you need to cut. There is one on each side. The big one is the hardest to find, I usually just start jabbing left with a scalpel and make my way up. The right one on the small one is in the bottom right corner, it has a little nip in it.

Comment: Yet another amazing question title for Arqade's front page.

Comment: I usually just stick the knife in and flail around wildly. If the blood loss gets too high, I just stab them (and usually myself) with the green syringe. :D

Comment: If this title was on any other SE site, I'd be worried.

Comment: @Ender Even better, it's on Hot Questions now - you can see it from _every_ StackExchange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two incision spots for each intestine, although they are a bit tricky to determine:

[image: Yronno Steam Screenshot: Medical Floppy Disk Britannia 88]

The small intestine needs to be cut twice on the top left, and the large intestine has to be cut once on the left side, and once on the bottom right. See [this guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=140160698) for more information.

Comment: i've done that but only the lower left part of the inner intestine cuts

Comment: @Lewis You must be doing it wrong then. This cutting diagram is taken directly from the game itself.